# autoconf configure warning: /usr/bin/file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, docker, configure, autoconf

When I use my configure in a ubuntu OS (16), there seems to be no problem. I have installed the autoconf tool and dependencies.

When I run the same configure file in a ubuntu (16 or latest) The problems is that I did not install any autotools. I am getting the following error message.

```
./configure: line 7022: /usr/bin/file: No such file or directory
```

This is harmless to the build process.  I just want to understand what's going on. The configure file:

```
7022     case `/usr/bin/file conftest.o` in
7023       *32-bit*)
```

It looks that my docker does not have /usr/bin/file.  Which ubuntu packages contain the file utility.  The problem with finding any useful information about '/usr/bin/file' is that file is such a common term, it is not easy to find more info.  On my system with the file utility, I can get the following info from the man page of file:

```
AVAILABILITY
     You can obtain the original author's latest version by anonymous FTP on ftp.astron.com in the direc‐
     tory /pub/file/file-X.YZ.tar.gz.
```

My question: is 'file' a very basic utility or it is recently added to the autotolls package? Should I install it?

Comment: Yes, `file` is a very basic utility. The package providing it is simply called `file`; see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file -- you should be using your operating system's package management facilities to install the vendor-provided binary package, not attempting to install from source.

Comment: By the way, if you want to google about a software package, "package" is an important keyword to add. Googling "ubuntu file package" brought up the above as the second link, and the one above it was also relevant.

Comment: Charles thanks for the comment, now I am clear.  The build-essential does not seem to include it.

Comment: I'm not particularly surprised by that -- `file` is a standard enough utility for it to be a reasonable expectation that any system that hasn't been stripped to bare minimal essentials will have it; and frankly, a minimal image isn't generally the right choice to use for builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNU Build System [restricts the features](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Portable-Shell) that `configure` is supposed to use for maximum compatibility, including how to write shell code and which [utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/standards.html#Utilities-in-Makefiles) are available for use, and features you can expect out of those utilities.

`file` is *not* in that list, and should be [tested for](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Generic-Programs) with `AC_PATH_PROG` (or something like that) and so is really a bug in the package.  Even if the test in `configure` absolutely requires `file` to work getting an `AC_MSG_ERROR` saying "Install the file program" would be preferable to decoding the error message.

So to answer your questions:

> is 'file' a very basic utility or it is recently added to the autotolls package?

No, file is not part of autotools, but it's a pretty common utility to be installed.  Basic might not be the best adjective to describe `file`.

> Should I install it?

Your `configure` script relies on it, so I guess you have to.

But it's usage is kind of silly: Most of the time you can determine the architecture from the [host triplet](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html).  Also, `objdump` is one of the standard compiler tools (`objdump -f conftest.o` will display similar info).  At least it's going to be installed.

Comment: The 'file' program is required by the generated code, and there is no apparent need for 'file' by configure.ac or Makefile.am.  Only exposed the dependency when running configure on a system without 'file' binary.

Comment: Right, but somewhere inside `configure.ac` (or one of the .m4 macros it uses) will be something that generates lines 7022-7023 when `autoconf` is run to generate the `configure` script..

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install -y file
```

or in Dockerfile:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y file
```

Comment: My error was "You must install '/usr/bin/file' on your build machine" and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

File appears to have its origin in BSD and has been evolving (man file).  This is a rare question, and I am not expecting any answers.  I am trying to accumulate some data.  After some detective work, I found that following link:

https://travis-ci.org/file/file  github page for implementation

unix file command: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufile.htm

wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)

As suggested by Charles, you should install the file package through a package manager.  For ubuntu the link to the package is: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file

Not sure which source is the authentic implementation.  I am not an OS expert, and others please comment and update.